# SOLR - Node: conflicts in 2 libraries

Tags: solr, solrclient

I was using solr-node library in node js.

> **solr-node**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-node

Function file of **solr-node**

> https://github.com/godong9/solr-node/blob/master/lib/query.js

So while writing query, I was not able to find for edismax bq query so I checked in the module's query file, **bq** was not available.

So I checked in another module **solr-client**

> **solr-client**: https://www.npmjs.com/package/solr-client

Function file of **solr-client**

> https://github.com/lbdremy/solr-node-client/blob/master/lib/query.js

Here I found the edismax bq query and it works as expected **So I moved to solr-client module and deleted the solr-node module**

> **NOW** >>>>>>>

I want to add **spellcheck** filter to query and the function is available in **solr-node** and not in **solr-client**

Is there any way to fix this?????

You can check both function file and search for **bq** and **spellcheck**

Comment: can you check with https://github.com/omeroot/solwr

Comment: You should be able to push custom arguments with `query.params.push('bq=field:foo')` with the first library as far as I can tell from the source.

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh, I checked the same in the solr-client file and I got the parameter array in which I can push the custom arguments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most libraries allow you to add custom parameters that isn't supported by the library itself. Sometimes it's documented, sometimes you have to read through the source to find it.

For your first example you can use:

```
query.params.push('bq=field:foo')
```

to add custom parameters (query refers to an instance of the Query object).